# crudbooster export xls field has no effect while using callback or callback_php

Tags: laravel-5.5, xls, crudbooster

Found a solution by commenting `// if (Request::input('fileformat') == 'pdf') {` on line 67 of export.blade.php, but dont know any issue come later